# How to valid a count over multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables (some code removed for brevity):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cluster] 
(
    [Id]       SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [IntentId] TINYINT  NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] SMALLINT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Cluster] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClusterMember] 
(
    [Id]        SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [ClusterId] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [PageId]    INT      NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ClusterMember] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ClusterMember_Page] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([PageId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PageNode] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ClusterMember_Cluster] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ClusterId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Cluster] ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClusterKeyword] 
(
    [MemberId]  SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [KeywordId] INT      NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ClusterKeyword] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MemberId] ASC, [KeywordId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ClusterKeyword_ClusterMember] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([MemberId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ClusterMember] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ClusterKeyword_Keyword] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([KeywordId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Keyword] ([Id])
);
```

`ClusterKeyword` links to `ClusterMember` which links to `Cluster`.

What I want to do is ensure that a `KeywordId` (`ClusterKeyword`) can only exist once per `Cluster`. However, because there can multiple `ClusterMembers` in a `Cluster`, I can't do it directly.

I can add a `ClusterId` to the `ClusterKeyword` table, but as I'm using an ORM this can get a bit messy. Instead, I'm considering a function.

I got started but then I'm out of my depth.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ClusterKeywordMismatches()
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN 
    RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM Cluster c
            LEFT JOIN ClusterMember cm ON cm.ClusterId = c.Id
            LEFT JOIN ClusterKeyword ck ON ck.MemberId = cm.Id)
END
```

This function will be added as a constraint on the `ClusterKeyword` table; it needs to return 1 to be valid - 1 being the number of keyword occurrences for a cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you need to ensure that the check function returns 0 to be valid. A value of 1 would indicate that a value already exists, in which case you would end up with a duplicate. You also need to pass in the value into your function for comparison sakes, which you are not doing above.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ClusterKeywordMismatches(@KeywordId INT)
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN 
    RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM Cluster c
            INNER JOIN ClusterMember cm ON cm.ClusterId = c.Id
            INNER JOIN ClusterKeyword ck ON ck.MemberId = cm.Id
            WHERE ck.KeywordId=@KeywordId)
END
```

And then bind the function to your table as a check constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClusterKeyword ]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_ClusterKeyword] CHECK  (([dbo].[ClusterKeywordMismatches]([KeywordId])=(0)))
```

Comment: The match is one, not zero but the addition of the where seems to work, Just doing a few more checks. Thanks

Comment: Just done some further checks. It works, but only to a degree. It limits the entry if a cluster already exists. However, looking at it, it needs tweaking. It needs to constrain the number to one, not for the cluster, but for the IntentId. So, there can be 2 entries for the cluster but they must have different intent. Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnOhara - Adding this tidbit now, might invalidate the answer. You could try COUNT(DISTINCT c.IntentID) and then compare that against 1 and not 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ross. The count looks like it will still return 2 if there are two different Intents. Whereas I'm looking for something slightly different - there can't be two rows for a single Intent but there can be many intents (with a single row). I need to return a single results so I'm guessing I will need to test if any intent groups are greater than 1 - if that makes sense.